# Ac wires/dog help

Tags: air-conditioning

My dog was messing around the ac unit outside.  Two wires red and white that are still attached to the ac unit are now hanging and I do not know where they attach to, any one have an idea?

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring damage please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Without more info all we could say would be "the wires connect to somewhere else". And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Those two wired carry the signal to start and stop that outdoor A/C Unit.  They have to be repaired in order for your A/C work.  You will need to find the other ends of these two wires and connect them back together.  Good Luck.

Before attempting any repairs involving removal of the cover on the unit be sure the power is off.